# placing multiple cursor on the vscode for linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to set the keyboard shortcut in vscode to `alt + left_click` for placing multiple cursors?

I could not find it in the '**keyboard shortcuts**' section.

I found one named `createCursor` but couldn't add any mouse input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the modifier in your `settings.json` or with the GUI

`editor.multiCursorModifier`

search for `multi cursor` in the GUI

Comment: The setting doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I just looked in VSC 1.75.0 and it still exists

Comment: Oh it's in File->Preferences->*Settings*, not File->Preferences->Keyboard shortcuts. I got confused because firstly CmdCtrl is a keyboard key, and secondly there confusingly is a similarly named keyboard shortcut: workbench.action.toggleMultiCursorModifier, and thirdly, if it's by defauly bound to Alt, why doesn't Meta+Alt simply work as a substitute for Alt? (this works in all other Linux (and even Wine) programs that need to ignore Alt-mouse behavior)